# Row/Col Name Vectors for Matrix in R on Data Camp

Tags: r, matrix

I'm working through R on DataCamp, this is my exercise:

```
# Box office Star Wars: In Millions (!) 
# First element: US, Second element: non-US 
new_hope <- c(460.998, 314.4)
empire_strikes <- c(290.475, 247.900)
return_jedi <- c(309.306, 165.8)

# Construct matrix
star_wars_matrix <- matrix(c(new_hope, empire_strikes, return_jedi), nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE)

# Add your code here such that rows and columns of star_wars_matrix have a name!
```

This is my original code:

```
colnames(star_wars_matrix) <- c("US", "non-US")
rownames(star_wars_matrix) <- c("A New Hope", "The Empire Strikes Back", "Return of the Jedi")
```

After getting frustrated and trying a bunch of different things, I succumbed to the help button and it gave me the solution, this:

```
rownames(star_wars_matrix) <- c("A New Hope", "The Empire Strikes Back", "Return of the Jedi")
colnames(star_wars_matrix) <- c("US", "non-US")
```

So my question is why? Do rows always come first when naming rows and cols in a matrix? I appreciate your time.

Comment: No. `colnames(star_wars_matrix) <- c("US", "non-US") ;rownames(star_wars_matrix) <- c("A New Hope", "The Empire Strikes Back", "Return of the Jedi")` is perfectly fine. Their algorithm is probably not smart enough.

Comment: @DavidArenburg - Their syntax/formatting is super picky. I tested it out a while back and it would reject perfectly good R code if it wasn't an exact match line for line.

Comment: @Zach Hoyle - report that to DataCamp's support. I beta tested a couple of courses and they are usually pretty quick to fix blatant errors like that.